# Is this operation $*$ binary on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Consider the operation $*$ on the set of reals $\mathbb{R}$ defined as follows:

> $a*b=c$, where $c$ is the smallest real number greater than both $a$ and $b$.

**My question**: Is the operation $*$ binary on $\mathbb{R}$?

**My confusion**: For an operation $*$ to be binary on set $S$, the closure property must be satisfied. I know that the result  $a*b=c$ surely belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ but can we say that the operation is *well-defined* for any pair $(a,b)$ as giving such $c\in\mathbb{R}$ explicitly is not possible? Thanks.

Comment: If you interpret *greater* as being strictly greater (*as opposed to greater than or equal*), then indeed it is not defined for any choice of $(a,b)$.  (*"well defined" usually refers to the property that $x=y\implies f(x)=f(y)$, I think you mean to use the phrase "undefined", "ill-defined" or "not defined" instead*)

Comment: @JMoravitz...I dn't think that  "greater than" has more than one meaning.

Comment: I really dn't understand the downvote for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A binary operation on a set $S$ is simply a function $f : S\times S\to S$. You need to check that $(a,b)\mapsto a\ast b$ is well-defined (i.e., actually a function whose codomain is $\Bbb R$).

The ``smallest real number greater than a given real number" is a problematic concept: there is no smallest real number greater than a given number! For example, consider $0$. What is the smallest real number greater than $0$? It would have to be the smallest positive number. But suppose there was one, and call it $\epsilon$. Then $0 < \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$, so $\epsilon/2$ is a smaller positive number than $\epsilon$, contradicting our assumption that $\epsilon$ was the smallest! A small modification of your argument shows that $a\ast b$ is not a well-defined real number (that is, no real number exists satisfying the defining property of $a\ast b$), so that $\ast$ is not a binary operation on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: It depends on whether "greater" means "strictly bigger" or "bigger or equal to" (and what OP intended probably depends on their native language). Because it could also be $a*b = \max(a,b)$.

Comment: Yes, if the OP's "greater" meant "bigger or equal to," it would be a well-defined binary operation. I'm used to "greater" as meaning "strictly bigger," so that was the interpretation I took.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi...."greater" means ">" and "greater or equal to" means "$\ge$" in any language.

Comment: @Stahl....you correctly interpreted what I meant to ask. Thanks for your nice answer.

Comment: @mathlover In French "supérieur à" ("bigger than") is always implicitly "supérieur ou égal" ("bigger than or equal", $\ge$). If you want a strict inequality, you need to say "strictement supérieur à" ("strictly bigger than", $>$). I sincerely doubt that you can speak every single language on Earth, so why do you presume that you know what words mean in every language?

Comment: @Najib Idrissi...With due respect to all languages of the world, what is the answer by a French person for the question "Is 2 'greater' than 2" ?

Comment: @mathlover In English, "no". Asked in French, "oui". If you read my first comment, I didn't know if your native language was English, and maybe you had assumed that the rules in English were the same as in your native language.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi...but why 'No'? As you said in your comments that 'bigger' means 'bigger than or equal', so '2 greater than 2' must be true in your native language.

Comment: @mathlover Have a good day.